# Robot Framework: How can I pass a list to a keyword in an if statement?

Tags: syntax, robotframework

I need help with Robot Framework syntax.
First usage of Log My List keyword is fine, logs the list perfectly. Second usage, in if statement keeps telling me:

> Value of variable '@{MyList}' is not list or list-like

Does anyone know what is the problem?

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Problematic Suite

*** Variables ***
${condition}    0

*** Keywords ***
Log My List ${MyList}
    Log Many   @{MyList}

*** Test Cases ***
LD_0: Pass List in If Statement.
    [Documentation]    Problem example.
    [Tags]    Problem
    @{LIST}=    Create List    item1    item2    item3
    Log My List ${LIST}
    Run Keyword If  ${condition} == 0    Log My List ${LIST}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in robot. If you switch from using embedded arguments to traditional arguments it will work.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Problematic Suite

*** Variables ***
${condition}    0

*** Keywords ***
Log My List
    [Arguments]  ${MyList}
    Log Many   @{MyList}

*** Test Cases ***
LD_0: Pass List in If Statement.
    [Documentation]    Problem example.
    [Tags]    Problem
    @{LIST}=    Create List    item1    item2    item3
    Log My List  ${LIST}
    Run Keyword If  ${condition} == 0    Log My List  ${LIST}
```